# Passing variables to a YAML array

Tags: arrays, rails-i18n, string-interpolation

How can I pass variables to a YAML array? The way I imagined it to work was like passing it to normal strings, like this (general example):

```
en:
  names:
    - First %{name}
    - Second %{name}
    - Third %{name}
```

```
t('names', name: 'foo')[0]
```

But this will render the text `First %{name}`. I know I could use explicitly indexed keys instead, like `name_0:`, `name_1:`, etc., but I see the YAML array as a much cleaner way and would like to make use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the `I18n` gem [interpolate function](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/3e5395036dd138a6dbf1148ecd4f14a56786f9fd/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb#L151), you will see that you can't do this by passing values, because if output is not `string` interpolate will no work.

But nothing prevents you to do the following:

```
t('names').map{|s| I18n.interpolate(s, name: 'foo')}
```

Comment: Hm, I see... In that case I might as well `t('names')[0].gsub('%{name}', 'foo')` since that's [basically what interpolate does](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/3e5395036dd138a6dbf1148ecd4f14a56786f9fd/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb#L21), but in both examples, `t('names.name_0', name: 'foo')` is easier.